# Work-around for module that performs (bad) initialization

Tags: python

We have a central module that within the module calls an init() function on loading:

```
import x
import y
import z

def init():
    ....

init()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ...
```

This gets pulled into every one of our application modules with a statement like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import central_module as b
    b.do_this()
    b.do_that()
```

init() does a number of bad things, notably establish connections to databases. Because of this, it breaks any unit tests, and the modules I write expect the usual behavior where you import the module and explicitly invoke any initialization.

I've implemented a work-around by adding an INITIALIZE variable up top:

```
#INITIALIZE = True
INITIALIZE = False  # for DEV/test

if INITIALIZE:
    init()
```

But requires me to edit that file in order to run my tests or do development, then revert the change when I'm ready to commit & push.

For political reasons, I haven't gotten any traction on just fixing it, with something like:

```
import central_module as b
...
    b.init()
    b.do_this()
    b.do_that()
```

Is there some way that I can more transparently disable that call when the module loads? The problem is that by the time the module is imported, it's already tried to connect to the databases (and failed).

Right now my best idea is: I could move the INITIALIZE variable into a previous import, and in my tests import that, set initialize to FALSE, then import central_module.

I'll keep working on the political side (arg), but was wondering if there's a better work-around I could drop in place to disable that init call without disrupting all the existing scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple change to your `INITIALIZE` hack would be to have that come from an environment variable. Then, you never have to modify code to run those tests, and less hackage until you can actually fix the bad init.

```
 INITIALIZE = os.environ.get('DO_TERRIBLE_INITIALIZE', False)
 if INITIALIZE:
     ....
```

And the value can be anything, as long as its set.

```
 export DO_TERRIBLE_INITIALIZE=ohgodwhy
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's my idea, evil as it may be:

1. Open the module as a file and read in the source.
2. Use `ast.parse()` to parse it into a AST.
3. Walk the AST until you find the offending function call, and prune it.
4. Evaluate the modified AST and inject it into a new module created by `imp.new_module()`, and stuff it into `sys.modules`.
5. Commit the crazy hack with a commit message saying that it shouldn't be necessary at all except for the fact that some twit wouldn't know proper initialization if it bit them in the ass.

Comment: Is there any way to do that through an `import` statement? I remember reading somewhere that `__import__` is called internally when you use `import`.

Comment: @Blender: There are ways to supplement *finding* modules, but I couldn't find a way to modify them on the fly while importing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want different behavior in testing and production environments, using an environment variable is standard:

```
import os

if os.getenv("MYAPPENV") != "test":
    init()
```

Then you need only set MYAPPENV to "test" when developing, and init() won't run upon load; if that variable isn't set in the environment, or has a value other than "test", you'll get the default behavior.  And you won't have to constantly re-edit the module's source file.

Comment: I went with @Bartek's answer, even though yours and his both use an environment variable, because a) he provided a default value so existing scripts wouldn't be disrupted, and b) his solution is a more targeted at the problem. In this case, I'd be wary of introducing the notion of "environment" -- I could see that growing hair over time. I just want some Roundup to spray on this particular weed. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem is specific to testing, the way I see it, init should be called, but with the bad things done on it (external procedures) being replaced by fake code. I think you should not avoid calling init.

Comment: There's some merit to that, but the code I'm writing is not dependent on the initialization done in that method -- intentionally. I don't want to set up fixtures that ultimately aren't used. That would be piling bad design on top of bad design. If that function actually becomes bad enough that it starts breaking things beyond that, then I'll have justification for pushing a better design.

Comment: Also, to be clear, my most frequent pain point is local development and testing, but this has caused problems in production. So I want to be careful about building up mechanisms that are dependent on this design -- that would just further cement it in place.